# Run commands in terminal via python

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, nohup

I have this python script(discord.py):

```
elif message.content.startswith('/mz stop'):   
     for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep /MYSCRIPT | grep -v grep"):
         fields = line.split()
         pid = fields[0]
         os.system('kill -9 '+pid)
elif message.content.startswith('/mz start'):
     bashCommand = "nohup bash start.sh"
     process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     output, error = process.communicate()
```

If I use /mz start in discord before /mz stop, "/mz stop" doesn't works. But If the command "/mz stop" before, it works and kill the process.
After /mz start i got this: `nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout` and python stdout is killed(I can't use `print()` )

Comment: It seems that the real problem here is that you are using `nohup`. Why do you want to run Bash from Bash from Python anyway?

Comment: Because I want to run script after logout!

Comment: Then this Python script should run with `nohup`, and any subprocesses (shell or otherwise) will inherit that.

Comment: `bashCommand = "bash start.sh"`?

Comment: and `nohup python3 script.py`?

Comment: Yeah well the Bash should not be necessary if the script has a proper shebang, and then putting `["start.sh"]` in a list yourself is easier than calling `split()` on the string.

Comment: Can you answer me with a full code? If you want!

Comment: I'm not sure if it will solve your problem and this snippet has many unrelated antipatterns which I don't have the time and energy to tackle right now.  Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway!